# while(true) does not equals while(!false)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, while-loop, client-server

I am currently working at a project developing a piece of client/server software. I had a strange problem and hopefully solved it, but I totally can't explain the cause and I searched for a long time.

I wanted to have a while(true) loop on server side to force the server to  continue accepting clients, after the one before has closed the socket.

So I tried to build it like this:

```
public void run() {

    Socket socket;

    while(true) {
        try {
            socket = server.accept();

            BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

            while (socket.isConnected()) {
                // TODO income handling
            }

            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

But I got an error message by Intellij telling me to add an end condition to this loop. But I have got one in the catch-statement. Changing

```
while(true)
```

to

```
while(!false)
```

have led the error message to disappear. Can anyone explain me the difference and why the first attempt did not work? I found it done this way multiple times during research.

Comment: Because IntelliJ has code to detect `while (true)` and not to detect `while (!false)`, apparently. In any case, an exception shouldn't be the only way that loop ends.

Comment: In the current IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate edition, 2017.3), I don't get neither warning, nor error on `while` for your code. For `!false` the only thing I get is that 'it can be simplified'.

Comment: Yeah, removing `break` statement you'll have a warning, but no warning when `break` is present. Also infinite loop inspection is smart enough to understand that `!false` is the same as `true`. Which version of IDEA are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're patching your app by doing this.

The IDE(IntelliJ) detects you're doing something you shouldn't and you trying to avoid IntelliJ try to prevent your bad practices by adding something even worse.

Change the condition to something that can finish at some moment or use a flag evaluation.

By the way, declare infinite classes and instances inside an infinite loop is a terrible bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the purpose of the IntellJ IDEA inspections is to help you quickly discover problematic code, not to make your life harder. 
You definitely should not change your code just to make your IDE happy.

This inspections ("'while' statement cannot complete without throwing an exception") produce warning by default. 
So if you really got an **error** then you probably accidentally changed settings for this inspections. 
List of available inspections along with their severity settings can be found in the Settings dialog at Editor > Inspections tab.

Regarding difference between `while (true)` and `while (!false)`: 
Both of them will produce equal byte code so there is no differences, just lack of this intention implementation.

If you don't want to see warnings for particular intention you can:

1. place text caret on highlighted code (`while` in this case)
2. press `Alt-Enter`
3. choose in the just opened context menu "Inspection 'Infinite loop statement' options"

And either

- disable it for this particular statement (menu item "Suppress for statement")
- disable this inspection completely (menu item "Disable inspection")
- or open settings dialog (menu item "Edit inspection profile settings").

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of the way you formatted the while loop condition. 
If the expression is complex or convoluted. The compiler does not realize the statements are identical, as T.J. Crowder stated above. Another explanation would be that the while(!false) that you created is not actually while(!false). Show what you changed the while loop to for more clear help from others.